# Relation between The Euler Totient, the counting prime formula and the prime generating Functions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, divisor-counting-function

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKFS0.png)
Relation between
The Euler Totient, 
the counting prime formula 
 and the prime generating Functions
There is a formula for the ivisor sum hiih is one of the most useful 
propertes of the Euler Formula to fond a relations with prime counting Formula ans sum of primes.
Proof : http://vixra.org/abs/1901.0046

Answer (score 1):

You are not really linking $\varphi(n)$ and $\pi(n)$. You are just adding things that cancel out.

$$\pi(n)=\sum\limits_{p\mid n}p+\sum\limits_{p\leq n, p\,\nmid \,n}1+\sum\limits_{d\neq p\mid n}\varphi(d)-n$$
$$\pi(n)=\sum\limits_{p\mid n}p+\sum\limits_{p\leq n, p\,\nmid\, n}1+\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)-\sum\limits_{p\mid n}\varphi(p)-n$$
$$\pi(n)=\sum\limits_{p\mid n}p+\sum\limits_{p\leq n, p\,\nmid\, n}1+n-\sum\limits_{p\mid n}(p-1)-n$$
$$\pi(n)=\sum\limits_{p\mid n}p-\sum\limits_{p\mid n}p+\sum\limits_{p\leq n, p\,\nmid\, n}1+\sum\limits_{p\mid n}1+n-n$$
$$\pi(n)=\sum\limits_{p\leq n}1$$
$\pi(n)$ is hidden in the second term 
$$\sum\limits_{p\leq n, p\,\nmid\, n}1$$
You could do that with any formula. Was there any reason to split it that way?